# Recursively downloading all files from a website's child directory using wget

Tags: wget

I am trying to recursively download the contents of a particular directory (via http from a web server) using wget. The command I am using is:

```
wget -r -l 0 --user=josh --ask-password http://morris.cs.example.com/files/Software/MySoftware/V2012_Linux
```

wget then appears to download the contents of the parent directories rather than just the intended child directory (V2012_Linux).

How do I modify my command to download only the contents of the child directory and also place it in a directory of my choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for

```
-np, --no-parent                 don't ascend to the parent directory.
```

Thus:

```
wget -r -l 0 -np --user=josh --ask-password http://morris.cs.example.com/files/Software/MySoftware/V2012_Linux/
```

Wget doesn't give much flexibility with output file names. If you want recursive downloading, you have to let the structure of the downloaded tree match the structure as served. Move `V2012_Linux` where you want it once the download is finished, or create a symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, your answer was helpful, however in my particular case, I needed to ensure that the trailing slash / was present. From wget's manual: "Note that, for HTTP (and HTTPS), the trailing slash is very important to ‘--no-parent’. HTTP has no concept of a “directory”—Wget relies on you to indicate what's a directory and what isn't. In ‘http://foo/bar/’, Wget will consider ‘bar’ to be a directory, while in ‘http://foo/bar’ (no trailing slash), ‘bar’ will be considered a filename (so ‘--no-parent’ would be meaningless, as its parent is ‘/’)."

Comment: @Josh Right, thank you, I'd forgotten about that.